# Styling Password Input Field W/ CSS

Tags: css

I just cannot seem to figure this out.  I need another set of eyes.

I am trying to style my password input box to look/react the same way as my text input boxes.

Here is the HTML:

```
<fieldset class="contact">
    <label for="full_name">Purchasing Account ID:</label>
    <input type="text" id="acc_id" name="acc_id" size="13" />
    <label for="email_address">Email Address:</label>
    <input type="text" id="email_address" name="email_address" size="13" />
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="pw" name="pw" size="13" />
</fieldset>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
form input[type=text], form input[type=password] {
    width: 306px;
    background: #f3f3f3;
    border-top: 1px solid #dedede;
    border-left: 1px solid #dedede;
    border-right: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #373737;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 3px 3px 5px #e9e9e9;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 3px 3px 5px #e9e9e9;
    box-shadow:inset 3px 3px 5px #e9e9e9;
}
form input[type=text]:focus, form input[type=password]:focus, form textarea:focus {
    border: 3px solid #c70000;
}
```

Any thoughts as to why the password input field is not getting CSS at all?  I inspected it with Google Chrome and the CSS is not getting applied at all to the password input field and Firebug shows the same thing.

Comment: Seems to work in Chrome and IE9: http://jsfiddle.net/9mcNr/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you tried this approach? 
Add a css class to your inputs, and then apply the styles via those classes.

http://jsfiddle.net/zr6yB/

```
<fieldset class="contact">
    <label for="full_name">Purchasing Account ID:</label>
    <input type="text" id="acc_id" name="acc_id" size="13" class="input-generic" />
    <label for="email_address">Email Address:</label>
    <input type="text" id="email_address" name="email_address" size="13" class="input-generic" />
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="pw" name="pw" size="13" class="input-generic" />
</fieldset>​
```

CSS (abbreviated)

```
.input-generic {
    width: 306px;
    ...etc...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
.Div_Class_Name input[type=text], .Div_Class_Name input[type=password] {
    background:#e5e2b6;
    border:2px solid #741a01;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  The reference for the CSS include was still referencing my live copy and not my development copy.